# In how many ways we can arrange two strings with distinct elements such that the order is intact?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

In how many ways we can arrange two strings (with distinct elements) such that the order is intact?

For example if the strings are , "aA" and "bk". The valid arrangements are: "aAbk","abAk","abkA","baAk","bakA" and "bkaA" and the invalid arrangements are "akbA", "Aabk". So, in this case the required answer is $6$.

I am looking for a combinatorial approach to solve this problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

If the first string has length $n_1$ and the second has length $n_2$, the answer is
$\binom{n_1+n_2}{n_1}=\binom{n_1+n_2}{n_2}$. Indeed, the arrangement is uniquely
determined when in the sequence of $n_1+n_2$ places you decide which are occupied
by characters from the first string. Then you have a set of $n_1$ places to fill with the characters of the first string in the correct order, and the remaining places form a  set of $n_2$ places to fill with the characters of the second string in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

well see it as a binary string 00 is aA and 11 is bk. now 0011,0101,0110,1001,1010,1100 are solutions, as you can see replacing the first 0 with a and second with A. and the first 1 with b and the second with k. we have all solutions. So this is just a binomial coefficient.

So let $s$ be the length of string 1 and $t$ be the length of string 2, then the count of all combinations is $\binom{s+t}{t}$.

In your example $\binom{4}{2} = 6$

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it, using the variables of Carlo Verschoor's solution:

Take $(s+t)$ things, s labelled "1" and t labelled "2".  These can be arranged in
$(s+t)!$ ways.  Then divide by $s!$ **and** $t!$ to give the **distinct** arrangements of 1's and 2's. Each arrangement is a different instruction set for selecting  the next available item from the indicated, ordered string.

For example, "112122121..." means to take the first two characters from the start of string #1, then next from the start of String #2, then the next  available in string #1, then the next two available in String #2, and so on...